# Brackets editor code suggestion

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'm using [the Brackets editor](http://www.brackets.io), and I ran into [this extension](https://github.com/MiguelCastillo/Brackets-Tern).
If you look at the picture on this extension's page you can see the small light bulbs next to some lines. I really want this feature, so I've installed the extension, but I can't see those light bulbs.
Is it a part of this extension or is it another extension in this picture?
If so, which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those icons come from the [Brackets Interactive Linter](https://github.com/MiguelCastillo/Brackets-Interactive-Linter) extension, created by the same author. However, they don't give you "auto correct" options like the lightbulbs in some other editors. As far as I can tell, the icon just shows you more details about the linting error.

If "auto correct" is what you're looking for, you might still be able to interest someone in working on that functionality. (The Brackets community is pretty responsive!).  I suggest:

1. File an issue in the extension's repo asking for the enhancement; or
2. Start a thread on the [brackets-dev forum](http://groups.google.com/group/brackets-dev) making this suggestion, in case any other extension developers would be interested in working on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AEM Brackets Extension and are unable to install the extension via url then either try to drag and drop the .zip into the DragDrop area or add your unzipped extension folder into \www\extensions\default directory and run the brackets tool via cmd line rather than double clicking on it.
It worked for me!!